# Synology NAS, Nginx, php-fpm, file not found

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm, synology

Hello and a happy new year!

I also get the very common but annoying error: "File not found".

Now, i am trying to be as precise as possible and hope somebody knows what the problem is. Short list of what i'm trying to do:

- Synology NAS with Container Manager
- Creating a folder on /volume1/web
- Creating a project with docker-compose.yml file

Here is my structure:

```
my_project/
    - .docker/
        - nginx/
            - conf.d/
                - default.conf
            - Dockerfile
        - php/
            - Dockerfile
    - logs/
        - nginx/
            - access.log
            - error.log
        - php/
            - php.log
    - src/
        - public/
            - index.html
            - index.php
    - .env
    - docker-compose.yml
```

Here is my code:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ./.docker/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
      - '8443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./.docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - internal

  php:
    container_name: php
    build:
      context: ./.docker/php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./logs/php/php.log:/var/log/fpm-php.www.log
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html/public;
    
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    
    charset utf-8;
    
    location \ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        try_files                         $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass                      php:9000;
        fastcgi_index                     index.php;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include                           fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

php/Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.3.1-fpm-alpine
```

nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.25.3-alpine
```

On my local docker it runs perfect, no issues. But when i try to create the project on my Synology NAS and want to open the input.php i get "File not found", while the html-file works.

So far i've tried a lot of solutions from here, stackoverflow and other sites, tutorials and so on. It is a very common problem and i guess i can't see a very simple solution...

Edit:

I've used absolute instead of relative paths. Still get the same error.
Changed chmod of folders and files - again. Still get the same error.

Here are the logs:
nginx/access.log

```
172.21.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2024:19:03:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 27 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

nginx/error.log -> empty

added an error.log in a volume to nginx container: - ./errors:/var/www/errors
Sometimes (not always) this error occures:

```
2024/01/04 19:13:48 [info] 31#31: *5 client timed out (110: Operation timed out) while waiting for request, client: 172.21.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

This i get with "docker ps":

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                            NAMES
986db5183632   paso4-nginx   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   22 minutes ago   Up 17 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8443->443/tcp, :::8443->443/tcp   nginx
cec07fa44c31   paso4-php     "docker-php-entrypoi…"   22 minutes ago   Up 22 minutes   9000/tcp                                                                         php
```

Get this with docker container top nginx

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                9420                9398                0                   20:27               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
101                 9509                9420                0                   20:27               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process
101                 9510                9420                0                   20:27               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process
101                 9511                9420                0                   20:27               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process
101                 9512                9420                0                   20:27               ?                   00:00:00            nginx: worker process
```

Get this with docker container top php:

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                5658                5636                0                   20:01               ?                   00:00:00            php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
82                  5738                5658                0                   20:01               ?                   00:00:00            php-fpm: pool www
82                  5739                5658                0                   20:01               ?                   00:00:00            php-fpm: pool www
```

Comment: To address  a `"File not found"` error you start  with *which* application is generating that error,  the *exact path to the file* that is not found and work your way up from there.

Comment: Thank you @HBruijn . I think the php-container is generating the error. Do you mean i should change some of the fastcgi_params in the default.conf? e.g. the root or  $fastcgi_path_info? ( I am sorry if i don't get you right. )

Comment: In the volumes path I would try to specify the exact path instead of relative paths. And check the logs with `docker logs container_name`

Answer (score 0):

Even though I'm a little embarrassed, I still want to share the solution. :-)

1. The user rights of the /src folder were wrong. The /public folder had 0755 which was right but the /src had none.
2. When i chmod the folders ( /src and /public ) by using the terminal (on mac and windows) i was - and that is the main reason for my embarrassment - not correctly connected with the nas. Only as a root user of the nas and not of docker.

Nevertheless many thanks!!!